# tables in Rmardown header

Tags: r

I have problems to be able to print my tables produced with R mardown I show an example  As you can see, the table is placed at the top of the page and I would like it to be just below the code

[image]

show preamble code

```
output: pdf_document
```

```
library(edstan)

preview_rows <- seq(from = 1, to = nrow(spelling), length.out = 10)
muestra<-as.data.frame(spelling[preview_rows, ])

kbl(muestra,booktabs=T) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options=c("striped"))
```

Comment: Read `?kable_styling()` under section `latex_options`.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(edstan)

preview_rows <- seq(from = 1, to = nrow(spelling), length.out = 10)
muestra<-as.data.frame(spelling[preview_rows, ])

kbl(muestra,booktabs=T) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options=c("striped","hold_position"))
```